# Grasper Is it a word?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adjectives

I want to describe a guy with quick **grasp** quality. Something like

> He is a quick ______.

So I think **grasper** would fit in here. But [the Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grasp?q=grasper#grasp__27) says **grasper** is a noun. I would like to use **grasp** as adjective in the given sentence. Is usage of **grasper** correct, or is there some other word from **grasp** that should be used, or I have to reform the sentence as there is no such word?

Comment: Your sentence requires a noun phrase in the blank, since it has a determiner (*a*) and is modified by an adjective (*quick*). If you put an adjective there you will still need a noun for it to modify.

Comment: You need to include the relevant definitions given, not just the fact that ODO lists 'grasper'.

Answer (score 1):

What you want in that sentence frame *is* a noun (or a noun phrase), so grammatically "grasper" will fit.

But to my ear, calling somebody a 'grasper', quick or not, would suggest first that they are 'grasping', i.e. avaricious, or greedy. I might understand your intended meaning eventually, but it is not the first thing that I would think of.

Answer (score 1):

The word **grasper** is not in either of the online [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=grasper) and [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=grasper&title=21st) dictionaries; but (as you have pointed out in the question) it is in the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grasp?q=grasper#grasp__27), which gives three example sentences:

> **[grasper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grasp?q=grasper#grasp__27)** *noun*
>   *It's time for them to stand up to the grabbers and **graspers**.*
>   *These trocars allow for passage of long, fiber-optic telescopes and narrow instruments, such as **graspers**, scissors, babcocks, and staplers, to perform the surgical procedure.*
>   *The **graspers** get more food, more resources and will always out-compete the misers, because when there are resources, the misers get less for their children.*

The first & third example sentences both illustrate that, when used to describe a person, the term is usually used in a derogatory manner, such as referring to people who grasp items / food quickly before others, who may be more deserving, have a chance to get something.